# Mongoose findOne returns empty array field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple embedded document:

```
{
    "username":"user001",
    "name":"John",
    "tasks":[
        {           
            "id":0,
            "title":"Candy",
            "description":"Lots of candy for you",
            "category":"food",
            "cost":2500,
            "candyTypes":[
                {"name":"gum", "type":"sweet", "price":"2"},
                {"name":"chocolate", "type":"tasty", "price":"3"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to query the task data through the mongo shell, I get everything:

```
db.users.findOne({ 'username': 'user001', 'tasks.id':4 }, {'tasks.$':1})

/* returns */

"tasks":[
    {           
        "id":0,
        "title":"Candy",
        "description":"Lots of candy for you",
        "category":"food",
        "cost":2500,
        "candyTypes":[
             {"name":"gum", "type":"sweet", "price":"2"},
             {"name":"chocolate", "type":"tasty", "price":"3"}
        ]
    }
]
```

But when I try to do the same in mongoose, the `candyTypes` array comes back empty:

```
Users.findOne({ 'username': username, 'tasks.id':taskId }, {'tasks.$':1}, function (err, data) {
        console.log(data);
}); 

/* returns */

"tasks":[
    {           
        "id":0,
        "title":"Candy",
        "description":"Lots of candy for you",
        "category":"food",
        "cost":2500,
        "candyTypes":[]
    }
]
```

I'm pretty new to MongoDB and Mongoose, but after searching and looking through documentation, I can't figure out what I'm missing.

**UPDATE**

I couple users requested it, so here is my mongoose schema:

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username:String,
    name:String,
    tasks:[{
        id: Number,
        title: String,
        description:String,
        category: String,
        cost: Number,
        candyTypes:[{
            title:String, 
            type:String, 
            value:String
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your schema definition ?

Comment: just try to  console your userName and taskId  are they same which you are using for mongo shell

Comment: Yes, they are the same. In fact I only have a single test user in this db

Comment: Can you try defining the `CandyTypeSchema` before the `UserSchema` ? 1. Define  `var CandyTypeSchema = new Schema({
  name:  String,
  type: String,
  value:String
        });` and 2. Reference in `tasks` attribute as `candyTypes:[CandyTypeSchema]`. I'm guessing its the deep embedding level that mongoose doesn't support/ like.

Comment: I am trying to avoid using references mainly because this is a very small amount of data and adding references and different schemas will unnecessarily increase the complexity of the overall app. Does Mongoose not support embedded data? I skimmed through their documentation but could not find anything about limitations on using embedded data. If that is the case, I may just have to ditch mongoose and go with a MongoClient driver

Comment: @PedroHoehlCarvalho I couldn't find anything about limiting embedded documents too. You can ask https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/ here. Usually they are very good with response.

Answer (score 0):

With Mongoose, you have to populate candyTypes array:

```
Users.findOne({ 'username': username, 'tasks.id':taskId }, {'tasks.$':1})
.populate('candyTypes')
.exec(function (err, data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

See docs: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: Hi Tyler, thanks for helping out. Strangely, I did try using `populate()` right before posting this question and I still got the same output.

Comment: I see that candyTypes is actually an array within the tasks array so you may have to use `.populate('tasks.candyTypes')`

Comment: I tried `.populate('tasks.candyTypes')` and got an error. Then I tried `.populate('tasks.$.candyTypes')` and got no error, but the same output as before.

Comment: `.populate({path: 'tasks',populate: { path: 'tasks.candyTypes }})`

Comment: Nope. Same issue. Thanks for trying to help though.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to you declaring a field called `type` which also has a special meaning in Mongoose, namely to signify the type of a field.

If you rename that field to something else (`candyType`), it'll probably work better.

Alternatively, you can use the [`typeKey`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey) option to make Mongoose use a different property name to signify field type.

As an aside, your document contains a field `price` but your schema names it `value`.